# How to change agora rtc video chat layout in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, agora.io

i'm trying to a make a video calling app using agora rtc and flutter, and i want to change it's layout from the split screen for both the dialer and the receiver to look more like Facetime, Whatsapp and or facebook video chat, how do i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) widget to place the Caller and Receiver view on top of each other along with the size specified for both the view.

If you want to move the view and place it some other side then you can wrap the above two widget inside [Draggable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html) and [DragTarget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DragTarget-class.html) widget.

If you want to expand or View in full screen one of the view then wrap the widgets with [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)widget and on tap change the view

Comment: thanks man, i forgot to respond, you helped alot